# Função em segundo plano com React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Tenho duas funções, uma que pega a posição atual da geolocalização e outra que executa essa função em um determinado período de tempo. Tenho um botão que utilizo para inicializar e pausar esta função, porém gostaria de executar esta função em segundo plano, enquanto o dispositivo estiver em bloqueado.

Atualmente o React Native tem o `Headless JS` para rodar funções em segundo plano. Fiz um teste simples com a função `GeolocationTask()` abaixo, que incrementa um valor e exibe um alert, mas não deu certo.

Gostaria de saber como utilizar o `Headless JS` corretamente ou alguma outra alternativa para executar funções mesmo com o dispositivo bloqueado ou o app em segundo plano.

**PS:** Estou utilizando [Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) para pegar as coordenadas, mas não coloquei aqui para simplificar, pois o objetivo é saber como executar funções mesmo com o app em segundo plano.

**GeolocationTask.js:**

```
module.exports = async (taskData) => {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    taskData++;
    alert(taskData.toString());
  }, 2000);
}
```

Obs: Importo este componente em uma tela faço a chamada ao pressionar um botão.

**index.android.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import GeolocationTask from './src/components/GeolocationTask';
import App from './src/App';

const appColeta = () => (
  <App />
);

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('GeolocationTask', () => GeolocationTask);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('appColeta', () => appColeta);
```

**GeolocationTask.java:**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;

public class GeolocationTask extends HeadlessJsTaskService {

  @Override
  protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  // Following line just to be sure it does not silently fail
  WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null;
  return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
    "GeolocationTask", // Use the registered headless Task here
    data,
    5000);
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appcoleta"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <service android:name=".GeolocationTask" android:enabled="true" android:label="GeolocationTask" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar o *Geolocation* do React-Native? Ele tem uma função watchPosition(), não é exatamente executar em segundo plano, mas talvez funcione. [Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html)

Comment: Pra você trabalhar com essa possibilidade, precisa implementar o AppState. Ele te informa através de eventos, quando o celular está ativo, inativo, etc. [Documentação AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html)